# Is there a way in ffmpeg to double up the frame rate without changing the runtime length of a video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, video-encoding

I have a video (B) that has 30 fps, and another video (A) that has 60 fps.

I need to merge them at 60 fps but I don't want video B to be shorter.

All videos are separate files, so I want to merge without re-encoding if possible.

Is this possible?

Comment: If by merge you mean concatenate you probably need to re-encode anyway, because the video streams may have different encoding settings.

Comment: Yes concatenate, and no the videos have the exact same settings except the FPS because I created them (screen recordings).

Comment: Well, changing FPS without changing it isn’t possible either way. Sophisticated video stream manipulation could be used to just duplicate all frames without re-encoding, but I’m not aware of such a thing.

Comment: Thanks you are right, maybe I will first look into creating the same video B as 60 fps at the same length, because that program will encode anyway, I just didnt want to perform 2 encodes due to quality issues.